# When using `getopts` with `case`: `*)` as the last pattern subclause, or `\?)` and `:)` as the last two pattern subclauses?

Tags: bash, getopts

When using `getopts` with `case` clause, is a `*)` pattern subclause as the last pattern subclause equivalent to the union of `\?)` and `:)` pattern subclauses as the last two pattern subclauses? Specifically,

```
while getopts "<optionString>" opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) a="$OPTARG"
           ;;
        b) b="$OPTARG"
           ;;

        ...
           ;;

        \?) printf "illegal option: -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        :) printf "missing argument for -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
           exit 1
           ;;
    esac
done
```

and

```
while getopts "<optionString>" opt; do
    case $opt in
        a) a="$OPTARG"
           ;;
        b) b="$OPTARG"
           ;;

        ...
           ;;

        *) printf "illegal option: -%s, or missing argument for -%s\n" "$OPTARG" "$OPTARG" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only really need to check for `:` and `?` with the `getopts` in `bash` if you use silent error reporting (when the first character of the `optstring` is a colon).

When `getopts` in not used in that way, it will produce its own diagnostic messages for invalid options and for missing option arguments (and these are usually quite adequate). In fact, it will not place `:` or `?` in the variable unless it's silenced.

Using `*` in a case statement would be a way to catch both of these, but if `getopts` is silenced, you would not know which error was triggered and would just be able to say something on the lines of `an error occurred while parsing the command line options` to the user.